# Parse - Send Push to Another User Using Custom Installation Data

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

In my app, users are assigned a Facebook ID to their installation when they are logged in for the first time:

```
PFInstallation *currentInstallation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];
[currentInstallation addUniqueObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)app.qbUser.ID] forKey:@"FacebookID"];
[currentInstallation saveInBackground];
```

Later in the app, my users should be able to send other users push notifications based on their FacebookID. I am using the code below, but it isn't working. Can anyone help me out?

```
NSString *userID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)[_userDict objectForKey:@"userID"]];

                PFQuery *userQuery=[PFUser query];
                [userQuery whereKey:@"FacebookID" equalTo:userID];

                PFQuery *pushQuery = [PFInstallation query];
                [pushQuery whereKey:@"Owner" matchesQuery:userQuery];
                PFPush *push = [PFPush new];
                [push setQuery: pushQuery];

                [push setData: @{ @"alert":[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ sent you a message",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"name"]]}];

                [push sendPushInBackground];
```

Comment: I should note that Step 1 (saving the user's FB information) is working fine. Step 2 (sending the other user a push) is the part I'm having trouble with

Comment: You set the id on the installation but then query for it on the user?

Comment: no, I'm trying to search the parse installation database for the ID of the user I'm trying to message (that information is stored in _userDict)

Answer (score 0):

You can change

```
PFInstallation *currentInstallation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];
[currentInstallation addUniqueObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)app.qbUser.ID] forKey:@"FacebookID"];
[currentInstallation saveInBackground];
```

with

```
 PFInstallation *currentInstallation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];

    if(![currentInstallation channels]) {

    [currentInstallation setChannels:@[@"WHATEVER1", @" WHATEVER2"]];
    NSLog(@"Set Channel");
} else {

 [currentInstallation addUniqueObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)app.qbUser.ID] forKey:@"FacebookID"];
[currentInstall addUniqueObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)app.qbUser.ID] forKey:@"channels"];
} [currentInstall saveInBackgroundWithBlock:(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {

if(!error){
    NSLog(@"subscribed user to both channels");
} else {
    NSLog(@"error subscribing to both channels: %@", error);
}
}];
```

This will set the push channel for the user to the Facebook id. You can then query for the Facebook id you need to send to then you can then send a push via below.

To send via channel you can use

```
[push setChannel:@"Facebook ID"]; //(where Facebook ID is the actual Facebook ID)
```

along with the rest of the code to push like the message.

Hope this helps.